# Beginner Facebook Application Questions

Tags: php, apache, facebook

I'm just getting into Facebook application development. I've got some questions about how the applications are developed.

First, there's the Facebook PHP SDK. You can install this to a web server capable of executing PHP, but does that mean if you went to www.example.com/facebook-php-sdk/examples/example.php that it would look like you're on Facebook.com but with your fully functioning application?

Second, when I configured apache to set the documentroot to /facebook-php-sdk/ I got white screens with every file - even with proper application ID and secret filled in.

Third, how do you set up to develop locally? I would like to have a sandbox where I can mess around, but the instructions are vague about how to get the PHP SDK going, I'm not sure what files I can edit where to get my "Hello, world!" on.

Thank you all for the help! I am very excited to start developing Facebook applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [**tutorial here**](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/09/20/developing-a-facebook-application-for-absolute-beginners/), a [**webcast here**](http://oreillynet.com/pub/e/1166) and a [**slide presentation here**](http://www.slideshare.net/junal/developing-facebook-application-for-beginners-1445669).
All for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check error logs of Apache in "/var/log/apache2/error.log" if you are on Linux. I also was getting blank page, but on error log I saw that I needed the cURL library to be installed.